# Android layout that will maintain the position of buttons on different screens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have to put transparent image buttons over a central dial in My design as [image: here]

what I did was to take an image button for the center dial. I also will put transparent buttons over each icon. And will use onclickListener() to see which button was pressed and update the  center dial background based on that to show which button was pressed

I am very new to android programming so this might be a very bad approach.

Now I need to place the buttons over the icons, I am using a relative layout, when i try to fix the positions for two buttons or more, the 2nd and so-on buttons change realative positions when screen size changes

here is my xml

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/ibRemote"
        android:src="@drawable/remote_selected"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/ibUsers"
        android:src="@drawable/users"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/ibArea"
        android:src="@drawable/areas"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/ibTimer"
        android:src="@drawable/timer_icon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</TableRow>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="288dp"
    android:id="@+id/cdial"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:background="@drawable/cd_inactive"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/disarmButton"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cdial"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to understand How can I place buttons on top the icons in such a way that they will maintain their positions with respect to each other on the dial on every screen size available

Comment: your English is unclear.

Comment: I want to place 8 buttons that should maintain their positions on different screens sizes. When I use relative layout as shown above, the position of buttons change if the screen size changes.